# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages and CRUD operation with Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am beginner to ASP.Net Core 3.1 and have to use Dapper in our project which need to be upgraded from webform to asp.net core 3.1 using Dapper as we use lot of store procedure and CTE queries on some page. We also have lot of data which is frequently queries.

I am at a very beginner level with no experience in MVC so my focus is on ASP.Net Core 3.1 razor pages using dapper, Unfortunately i am not abel to find complete tutorials on net with using Razor pages & dapper. Most o fthe example & tutorials are for ASP.net core MVC & EF based.

I am trying to convert [Blazor dapper example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-blazor-server-spa-with-dapper/) into asp.net core razor pages and i am stuck on how to show data on employee.cshtml.cs

```
      using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using BookListRazor.Data;
using BookListRazor.Model;

namespace BookListRazor.Pages
{
    public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;
        public EmployeeModel(SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> EmployeeList{ get; set; }

        public IEmployeeService _employeeService;


        public async Task OnGet()
        {

            EmployeeList = await _employeeService.GetEmployees();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
I am not able to make a call to `GetEmployees()` function in `EmployeeDapperService.cs` class. I need help so that i can list all employee and from there i will also work on Insert & Update.

Below is the complete code for project

Folder Structure & files

```
-Data
--EmployeeDapperService.cs
--IEmployeeService.cs
--SqlConnectionConfiguration.cs

-Model
--Employee.cs

-Pages
--Index.cshtml
--Employee.cshtml

Startup.cs
```

**EmployeeDapperService.cs**

```
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookListRazor.Model;
using BookListRazor.Data;

namespace BookListRazor.Data
{
    public class EmployeeDapperService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;
        public EmployeeDapperService(SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public async Task<bool> CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                const string query = @"insert into dbo.Employees (Id,Name,Department,Designation,Company,City) values(@Id,@Name,@Department,@Designation,@Company,@City)";
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    await conn.ExecuteAsync(query, new { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), employee.Name, employee.Department, employee.Designation, employee.Company, employee.City }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(string id)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                const string query = @"delete dbo.Employees where Id=@Id";
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    await conn.ExecuteAsync(query, new { id }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> EditEmployee(string id, Employee employee)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                const string query = @"update dbo.Employees set Name = @Name, Department = @Department, Designation = @Designation, Company = @Company, City = @City where Id=@Id";
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    await conn.ExecuteAsync(query, new { employee.Name, employee.Department, employee.Designation, employee.Company, employee.City, id }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees()
        {
            IEnumerable<Employee> employees;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                const string query = @"select * from dbo.Employees";

                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    employees = await conn.QueryAsync<Employee>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
            return employees.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<Employee> SingleEmployee(string id)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                const string query = @"select * from dbo.Employees where Id=@Id";

                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    employee = await conn.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Employee>(query, new { id }, commandType: CommandType.Text);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
            return employee;
        }
    }
}
```

**IEmployeeService.cs**

```
using BookListRazor.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookListRazor.Data
{
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees();
        Task<bool> CreateEmployee(Employee employee);
        Task<bool> EditEmployee(string id, Employee employee);
        Task<Employee> SingleEmployee(string id);
        Task<bool> DeleteEmployee(string id);
    }
}
```

**SqlConnectionConfiguration.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookListRazor.Data
{
    public class SqlConnectionConfiguration
    {
        public SqlConnectionConfiguration(string value) => Value = value;
        public string Value { get; }
    }
}
```

**Employee.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookListRazor.Model
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Startup.cs** partial code

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeDapperService>();
var sqlConnectionConfiguration = new SqlConnectionConfiguration(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlDbContext"));
        services.AddSingleton(sqlConnectionConfiguration);
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    }
```

**Employee.cshtml.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using BookListRazor.Data;
using BookListRazor.Model;

namespace BookListRazor.Pages
{
    public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
    {

        //for Dapper
        private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;
        public IEnumerable<Employee> EmployeeList{ get; set; }

        public readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            // Employees = await employees.

            // Employees = await 

            EmployeeList = await _employeeService.GetEmployees();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From your image above and the VisualStudio intellicense I get the feeling that you are trying to call instance methods without having an instance of `EmployeeDapperService`. If that is the case you will need to inject it from the constructor of your controller and add a transient mapping in your startup `ConfigureServices` like  `services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService,EmployeeDapperService>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your image above and the VisualStudio intellicense I get the feeling that you are trying to call instance methods without having an instance of `EmployeeDapperService`.

If that is the case you will need to inject it from the constructor of your `employee.cshtml.cs` page model and add a transient mapping in your startup `ConfigureServices` like `services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService,EmployeeDapperService>();`

### edit

## Employee.cshtml.cs

```cs
    public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public IEmployeeService EmployeeService { get; }

        public EmployeeModel(IEmployeeService employeeService) {
            EmployeeService = employeeService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employeeService));
        }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
           Employees = await EmployeeService.GetEmployees();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that may be the case .. Let me try.. for this reason i almost added all the code..

Comment: I did add `services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService,EmployeeDapperService>();` but i am not getting anything in employee,cshtml .cs page page

Comment: @Learning you will also need to introduce a property in your employee.cshtml.cs like so `public IEmployeeService EmployeeService { get; set; }` and inject it thorough constructor injection. Then instead of using directly the class name `EmployeeDapperService` use the propery to call your data access methods `GetEmployees();` etc.

Comment: Can  you plz show me full code as i followed your instruction but its not working..

Comment: @Learning put a break point inside the contructor I created in my edit above. And see if the framework gives you an instance of the IEmployeeService to use.

Comment: I did follow you code it give following error `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.`  

`BookListRazor.Data.EmployeeDapperService.GetEmployees() in EmployeeDapperService.cs

                    conn.Open();

BookListRazor.Pages.EmployeeModel.OnGet() in Employee.cshtml.cs

                Employees = await EmployeeService.GetEmployees();
`

Comment: I also updated EMployee page code in my question but it gives a different error to me..

Comment: @Learning it seems to me that your question was indeed answered. Now you have progressed to the next part which is when you call your GetEmployees() method you cannot open a Database connection. This is an other question and you should not be changing this one as you progress. (you are probably missing a connection string named `SqlDbContext` in your appsettings.json check your `ConfigureServices` to see what I mean)